# qmake: generate include other Makefile in Makefile

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

Is there a way to tell qmake to add to Makefile an include directive to include other Makefile.

I need at the beginning of generated Makefile added one line:

include custom.inc

Maybe there is just a way to output text to Makfiles from qmake but I could not find.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the undocumented `QMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDES` variable, like

`QMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDES += /path/to/your/file.mk`

Answer (score 0):

you can define a new target into make file and then tell what that target does:

```
mytarget.target = .buildfile
mytarget.commands = make -f AnotherMakeFile
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mytarget
PRE_TARGETDEPS += .buildfile
```

last 2 statements add your target .buildfile to Makefile and mytarget to Qt compiling process

here you can get further info: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html

Comment: It does not help me. I do not want to execute another Makefile but all I need is to get inluded a Makefile that defines certain vars.

Comment: that was an example. If you use a bash shell to include another makefile you can use both: `source OtherMakeFile` or: `. OtherMakeFile` instead of "make -f AnotherMakeFile" command...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to include a Makefile, but I have had a similar problem where I wanted one file to contain a common set of build variables.  The solution I came up with was to use the QMake command `include(filename.pro)` (see [QMake reference page](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.8-snapshot/qmake-project-files.html#built-in-functions-and-control-flow)).  This causes QMake to include another project file.  In my case, that contained all of the common settings.